# Spring + Hibernate Getting 500 erorcode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao, pojo

now i want to play with spring+hibernate with oracle database
i've got some problem in the java controller i hope someone can help me.

Authentication Controller

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticateService auth;

@RequestMapping(value = "auth",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView proses(@RequestParam("user")String username,@RequestParam("password")String password){
    String message = "invalid Credential";
    if (auth.verify(username, password)) {
        message = "welcome"+username;
    }
    return new ModelAndView("result","message",message);
}
```

Pojo Class

```
package com.badak.pp.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public abstract class AbstractCssUsr implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private String userId;
    private String pwd;
    private String active;
    private String ldapFlag;
    private String ldapUser;
    private String allowLoginas;
    private String name;

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public AbstractCssUsr() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public AbstractCssUsr(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public AbstractCssUsr(String userId, String pwd, String active,
            String ldapFlag, String ldapUser, String allowLoginas, String name) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.active = active;
        this.ldapFlag = ldapFlag;
        this.ldapUser = ldapUser;
        this.allowLoginas = allowLoginas;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Property accessors

    public String getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return this.pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return this.active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getLdapFlag() {
        return this.ldapFlag;
    }

    public void setLdapFlag(String ldapFlag) {
        this.ldapFlag = ldapFlag;
    }

    public String getLdapUser() {
        return this.ldapUser;
    }

    public void setLdapUser(String ldapUser) {
        this.ldapUser = ldapUser;
    }

    public String getAllowLoginas() {
        return this.allowLoginas;
    }

    public void setAllowLoginas(String allowLoginas) {
        this.allowLoginas = allowLoginas;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

CssUsr Class

```
package com.badak.pp.model;

/**
 * CssUsr entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */
public class CssUsr extends AbstractCssUsr implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public CssUsr() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public CssUsr(String userId) {
        super(userId);
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public CssUsr(String userId, String pwd, String active, String ldapFlag,
            String ldapUser, String allowLoginas, String name) {
        super(userId, pwd, active, ldapFlag, ldapUser, allowLoginas, name);
    }

}
```

CssUsrDAO class

```
package com.badak.pp.model;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.LockMode;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Example;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class CssUsrDAO extends BaseHibernateDAO {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CssUsrDAO.class);
    // property constants
    public static final String PWD = "pwd";
    public static final String ACTIVE = "active";
    public static final String LDAP_FLAG = "ldapFlag";
    public static final String LDAP_USER = "ldapUser";
    public static final String ALLOW_LOGINAS = "allowLoginas";
    public static final String NAME = "name";

    public void save(CssUsr transientInstance) {
        log.debug("saving CssUsr instance");
        try {
            getSession().save(transientInstance);
            log.debug("save successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("save failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void delete(CssUsr persistentInstance) {
        log.debug("deleting CssUsr instance");
        try {
            getSession().delete(persistentInstance);
            log.debug("delete successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("delete failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public CssUsr findById(java.lang.String id) {
        log.debug("getting CssUsr instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            CssUsr instance = (CssUsr) getSession().get(
                    "com.badak.pp.model.CssUsr", id);
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public List findByExample(CssUsr instance) {
        log.debug("finding CssUsr instance by example");
        try {
            List results = getSession()
                    .createCriteria("com.badak.pp.model.CssUsr")
                    .add(Example.create(instance)).list();
            log.debug("find by example successful, result size: "
                    + results.size());
            return results;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("find by example failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public List findByProperty(String propertyName, Object value) {
        log.debug("finding CssUsr instance with property: " + propertyName
                + ", value: " + value);
        try {
            String queryString = "from CssUsr as model where model."
                    + propertyName + "= ?";
            Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
            queryObject.setParameter(0, value);
            return queryObject.list();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("find by property name failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public List findByPwd(Object pwd) {
        return findByProperty(PWD, pwd);
    }

    public List findByActive(Object active) {
        return findByProperty(ACTIVE, active);
    }

    public List findByLdapFlag(Object ldapFlag) {
        return findByProperty(LDAP_FLAG, ldapFlag);
    }

    public List findByLdapUser(Object ldapUser) {
        return findByProperty(LDAP_USER, ldapUser);
    }

    public List findByAllowLoginas(Object allowLoginas) {
        return findByProperty(ALLOW_LOGINAS, allowLoginas);
    }

    public List findByName(Object name) {
        return findByProperty(NAME, name);
    }

    public List findAll() {
        log.debug("finding all CssUsr instances");
        try {
            String queryString = "from CssUsr";
            Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
            return queryObject.list();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("find all failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public CssUsr merge(CssUsr detachedInstance) {
        log.debug("merging CssUsr instance");
        try {
            CssUsr result = (CssUsr) getSession().merge(detachedInstance);
            log.debug("merge successful");
            return result;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("merge failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void attachDirty(CssUsr instance) {
        log.debug("attaching dirty CssUsr instance");
        try {
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
            log.debug("attach successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("attach failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void attachClean(CssUsr instance) {
        log.debug("attaching clean CssUsr instance");
        try {
            getSession().lock(instance, LockMode.NONE);
            log.debug("attach successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("attach failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```

Application Context generated by hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation"
            value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml">
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean   id="transactionManager" 
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />    
</beans>
```

and the auth.jsp

```
<c:if test="${! empty view}">
            <c:forEach var="user" items="${view}">      
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user.NAME}"></c:out></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

the error

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken [from com.badak.pp.model.CssUsr]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.panic(HqlLexer.java:80)
    at antlr.CharScanner.setTokenObjectClass(CharScanner.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.setTokenObjectClass(HqlLexer.java:54)
    at antlr.CharScanner.(CharScanner.java:51)
    at antlr.CharScanner.(CharScanner.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.(HqlBaseLexer.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.(HqlBaseLexer.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.(HqlBaseLexer.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.(HqlLexer.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlParser.getInstance(HqlParser.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1651)
    at com.badak.pp.model.CssUsrDAO.findAll(CssUsrDAO.java:123)
    at com.badak.pp.controller.HelloController.getAllContacts(HelloController.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:221)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

i dont got any idea to solve this, because i am new in spring , could help me

Comment: Look in the logfiles for more informations

Comment: Show us exception. Then we could help you.

Comment: It is saying org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken. Looks like some jars or this class is missing.

Answer (score 0):

So you are running weblogic server. That means server has own implementation of some libraries and you need to make this:

First shot: [Weblogic and `ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702266/classnotfoundexception-hqltoken-when-running-in-weblogic)

or

Second shot: [Weblogic and `ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819450/classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hql-ast-hqltoken-when-ever-i-am-trying-to)

And propably it is `ANTLR` library

Comment: i have those particular library installed on my project, i think not the libs was fault

Comment: Was or still is? Have you considered that case described by me? Have you tried it? Dont be fooled about libs in project beacuse weblogic has own implementation of libs and therefore it overrides yours in web application deployed on that server.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your `CssUsr Class` with `@Entity`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class as bean class in hibernate.hbm.cfg file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.jwt.hibernate.bean.User" table="CssUsr">
        <id column="userId" name="userId" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="pwd" name="pwd" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="active" name="active" type="string" />
        <property column="ldapflag" name="ldapflag" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="ldapuser" name="ldapuser" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="allowLoginas" name="allowLoginas" type="java.lang.String" />
<property column="name" name="name" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```